# best practice to host redis server on Amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I'm new to redis now i'm trying to host the redis on amazon EC2 instance which i did. My question is Do we need a complete new EC2 instance to host redis or can we use the same instance where we hosted server. Which would be the best practice, Please suggest me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the server loads that you're expecting and your plans for scaling your infrastructure.

A. If you're looking to scale horizontally (add more and more EC2 instances) then you should move Redis to it's own machine, so that you can decouple the web-servers instances from the DB

B. If you're just looking to scale vertically (upgrade your EC2 instance more and more), or you don't expect traffic to exceed your current allocated resources, then you could go ahead and host Redis on the same machine as the web server. In this case, you should make sure that each server (DB and WebServer) get at least one core each.

C. If you're using redis for caching, not a DB for all web-server instances, you could go ahead with a setup where each web-server has it's own Redis caching instance. Also, in this case, make sure that enough RAM and CPU resources are available for each server.

Edit: for case A, here's what a typical scenario would look like

- create two security groups, one for web servers (secWeb), one for the DB layer(secDB)
- secWeb only opens ports 80 and 443 (http/s)
- secDB only opens port 6379 for traffic from secWeb (or what port you defined redis to run on)
- set up two initial EC2 instances (one for the web server, one for the DB) and install everything on them
- assign an Elastic IP to your Redis instance, and configure the Web server to connect to redis via this IP:port
- create an ELB instance in front of the Web server instances and use the ELB endpoint for your main traffic (you can assign a CNAME pointing to it from your main domain DNS zone)
- set up an autoscaling policy for the EC2 Web servers based on your preferences

This should get you going initially.

Comment: Thanks, Im trying to scale it horizontally depending in the load so can u explain me a little breifly why should i go with it